# Install pgvector extension on mac

Tags: postgresql, machine-learning, vectorization

I'm trying to install postgres vector extension on my mac but am getting

```
ERROR:  extension "vector" has no installation script nor update path for version "0.4.0".
```

Here's what I did:

1. Follow the installation guide as shown on [github](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector):
   [image]

But when I ran `CREATE EXTENSION vector;` got an error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/share/postgresql/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory
```

2. I copied the content of pgvector into posgresql/extension using:

   sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/pgvector/* /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/share/postgresql/extension/

Tried running `CREATE EXTENSION vector;` now the error is:

```
ERROR:  extension "vector" has no installation script nor update path for version "0.4.0".
```

Anyone here seen this problem?

By the way am using `PostgreSQL 13.10`

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Copying the files directly to the pg extensions directory creates an invalid directory structure. See my Answer below on how to fix.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and was able to fix it.

### My Setup

- postgres v 14
- installed via Postgres.app

### First Mistake (mixed PG config)

Even though I installed PG via the PG app, I tried to install this
extension using Homebrew.
This messed up some of the PG config settings.

Running this on the command line,

```
pg_config --libdir
```

> Gave this output: /opt/homebrew/share/postgresql@14

This is not good for a Postgres.app install.

**The Fix (reset pg configs)**

*Assuming Postgres.app install!*

```
brew uninstall pgvector

brew uninstall postgresql
```

Now run:

```
pg_config --libdir
```

> I get: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/lib

Now, install pgvector using the Makefile approach.

### 2nd Mistake (Extension files in the wrong place)

Don't (as OP did), just copy the pgvector files to the Postgress extensions directory. This will create an invalid directory structure.

I believe make install will place the files in the proper place.
If
CREATE EXTENSION vector; still fails, you can check the following to ensure the files are in the right place.

**The Fix**

You should have the following files installed in the following directories.

All .SQL and .control files.
Ensure these files are in the following directory

> /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/share/postgresql/extension

vector.so is in the following directory

> /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/lib/postgresql

Install the extension

```
psql <your db>
CREATE EXTENSION vector;
```

Comment: i wasn't expecting this error, but following this solution finally worked.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue.
After installation, you have to login to your Postgres DB, for example via

```
psql postgres
```

and run

```
CREATE EXTENSION vector;
```

Comment: This is what I get:

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION vector;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/share/postgresql/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory

Comment: @Andrei make sure you are using the latest postgres.app version from https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [pgvector docs](https://ERROR:%20%20could%20not%20open%20extension%20control%20file) you can do install pgvector with Homebrew.

```
brew install pgvector
```

Then connect to your postgres server:

```
psql postgres
```

And create the extension:

```
create extension vector;
```